# Navigate from Fragment to Activity MVVMCross

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I am struggling to perform a navigation from a Fragment to an Activity at ViewModel level. I have an Activity with a DrawerLayout and this Activity has a FrameLayout to display different Fragments selected from the DrawerLayout. That navigation is perform by the ViewModel of this Activity and it is calling the ViewModel of each Fragment to display. In one of the Fragments I added a button binding a IMvxCommand method to perform the navigation from the Fragment to a new Activity and here is where I have the problem because when I click on the button nothing happens.

Find below my code.

**ViewModel of Fragment**

```
public class MainFrameViewModel : ContentViewModel
    {
        readonly IMvxNavigationService navigationService;

        public MainFrameViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
        {
            this.navigationService = navigationService;
        }

        public IMvxCommand GoMoreInfo
        {
            get
            {
                IMvxCommand navigateCommand = new MvxCommand(() => navigationService.Navigate<MoreInfoViewModel>());
                return navigateCommand;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Fragment code**

```
[MvxFragmentPresentation(typeof(ContentViewModel), Resource.Id.frameLayout)]
    [Register("mvvmdemo.droid.views.fragments.MainFrameFragment")]
    public class MainFrameFragment : MvxFragment<MainFrameViewModel>
    {
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MainFrame, container, false);
        }
    }
```

**Activity to navigate**

```
[MvxActivityPresentation]
    [Activity(Label = "MoreInfoActivity")]
    public class MoreInfoActivity : MvxAppCompatActivity<MoreInfoViewModel> 
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MoreInfoLayout);
        }
    }
```

ContentViewModel is the ViewModel of the Activity containing the FrameLayout and the DrawerLayout.

Answer (score 2):

Your bindings aren't working because you are using the default inflater, which knows nothing about MvvmCross bindings. You could solve this problem by using the MvvmCross inflater inside `OnCreateView`. Change `return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MainFrame, container, false);` call to `return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.MainFrame, null);`

Also, you are ignoring the async part of the `IMvxNavigationService`. It would be an improvement to change from `IMvxCommand` to `IMvxAsyncCommand` and `await` or return the `Task` returned by `IMvxNavigationService.Navigate()`

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, I was out the last week. I have changed the inflater to use MvvmCross binding inflater but I am getting the exception System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.